Extremely slow rendering for reversed video strip in Sequencer
I noticed that in the Video Sequencer when I enable Reverse Frames for a cut-out video strip under N > Strip > Video, and then render the MP4, the rendering becomes extremely slow when it reaches these reversed video strips. This is a problem if I have to reuse this reversed strips. How can this be? It makes no sense. The current workaround is to render the reversed strip and then import it again, but that will still require me to render it, which will take forever. Is there a better way to accomplish reversing a video strip instead of rendering it out and re-importing? Maybe some other way to apply reversing?

It makes sense. The standard compression algorithm stores the movement of pixels from frame to frame (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types). This means that when playing backwards, you have to read data through multiple frames to get the current frame.

@Lutzi thank you for sharing :) Still the lag I'm experiencing is way too extreme. Why does it work fine for other video editors like Corel Video Studio? I used to be able to reverse frames and render that at no additional overhead.

Video streaming in Blender is quite unoptimized I think, and the VSE in general is one of the least updated feature. Compared to DaVinci, Blender has quite a long journey of video streaming optimization.

@Lutzi good point hehe. Thank you for inputs.

@Lutzi I checked also with using Strip Effect and set multiply to zero so I can freeze the frame and get same effect: it gets really slow so I think it's not the compression algorithm but some buggy implementation.
